# Dividing a geographic region

Tags: matlab, geospatial, geography, gis

I have a certain geographic region defined by the bottom left and top right coordinates. How can I divide this region into areas of 20x20km. I mean in practial the shape of the earth is not flat it's round. The bounding box is just an approximation. It's not even rectangular in actual sense. It's just an assumption. Lets say the bottomleft coordinate is given by x1,y1 and the topright coordinate is given by x2,y2, the length of x1 to x2 at y1 is different than that of the length between x1 to x2 at y2. How can I overcome this issue

Actually, I have to create a spatial meshgrid for this region using matlab's meshgrid function. So that the grids are of area 20x20km.

```
meshgrid(x1:deltaY:x2,y1:deltaX:y2)
```

As you can see I can have only one deltaX and one deltaY.  I want to choose deltaX and deltaY such that the increments create grid of size 20x20km. However this deltaX and deltaY are supposed to vary based upon the location. Any suggestions?

I mean lets say deltaX=del1. Then distance between points (x1,y1) to (x1,y1+del1) is 20km. BUt when I measure the distance between points (x2,y1) to (x2, y1_del1) the distance is < 20km. The meshgrid function above does creates mesh. But the distances are not consistent. Any ideas how to overcome this issue?

Comment: (x2, y1_del1) should be  (x2, y1+del1). If I am right then update the question please

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that 20km on the surface of the earth is a REALLY short distance, about .01 radians - so the area you're looking at would be approximated as flat for anything non-scientific.  Assuming it is scientific...

To get something other than monotonic steps in meshgrid you should create a function which takes as its input your desired (x,y) and maps it relative to (x_0,y_0) and (x_max,y_max) in your units of choice.  Here's an inline function demonstrating the idea of using a function for meshgrid steps

```
step=inline('log10(x)');
[x,y]=meshgrid(step(1:10),step(1:10));
image(255*x.*y)
colormap(gray(255))
```

So how do you determine what the function should be?  That's hard for us to answer exactly without a little more information about what your data set looks like, how you're interacting with it, and what your accuracy requirements are.  If you have access to the actual location at every point, you should vary one dimension at a time (if your data grid is aligned with your latitude grid, for example) and use a curve fit with model selection techniques (akaike/bayes criterion) to find the best function for your data.